# Why async / long running operations in BackgroundTasks don't work?

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to use `BackgroundTasks` for iOS 13+. Long running operations don't seem to work:

```swift
// in AppDelegate

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "foo.bar.name", using: nil) { task in
         print("start!")

         task.expirationHandler = {
             // Not executed
             print("expired!")
         }
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
             // Not executed
             print("finish!")
             task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
         }
     }

     return true
 }

 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
     BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
     let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "foo.bar.name")
     request.earliestBeginDate = nil // or Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0) or Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)...
     do {
       try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
     } catch let e {
         print("Couldn't submit task: \(e)")
     }
 }
```

I also tried using a queue with `Operation` (for which I modeled my flow synchronously). This also didn't work. As soon as there's something that takes a while to complete, it gets stuck.

It doesn't log anything else to the console, no errors, no expired task message. It shows the last message before the long running operation and that's it. I confirmed that it doesn't move forward by storing a preference and examining it when restarting. It's not stored.

I added "foo.bar.name" to the info.plist (in "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers") and enabled capabilities both for background fetch and background processing. I'm testing on an iPhone with iOS 13.3.1 and using Xcode 11.4.1.

Additional notes:

- I've been starting the tasks immediately as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development
- I also tested with Apple's [demo project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks). It shows the same problem: The database cleaning operation doesn't complete (I added a log at the beginning of `cleanDatabaseOperation.completionBlock` and it never shows).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

1. You should check the result code of `register`. And you should make sure you didn’t see your “Couldn't submit task” log statement.
2. Per that discussion in that [link you shared](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development), did you set your breakpoint *immediately* after the `submit` call? This accomplishes two things:

   - First, it makes sure you hit that line (as opposed, for example, to the `SceneDelegate` methods).
   - Second, if you just pause the app manually, some random amount of time after the app has gone into background, that’s too late. It has to be in that breakpoint *immediately* after you call `submit`. Then do `e` command. Then resume execution.

Anyway, when I do that, running your code, the `BGProcessingTaskRequest` ran fine. I’m running iOS 13.4.1 (and like you, Xcode 11.4.1).

Comment: There was not logged error. I checked (now) the result of register too and it's true. I did mention `BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers` and the capabilities in the post. It's set. I set the breakpoint in the immediate next line to `submit`. I run the `e` command, disable breakpoint and click resume.

Comment: Fascinating. Well, it worked as advertised on my 13.4.1 device. I’m unable to reproduce the behavior you describe...

Comment: Okay. I'll +1 this and come back when I figure out what the problem is (which I hope will be soon). Thanks!